# how can i make image view disapper after opening webview

Tags: android, android-studio

i have buttons also which disapper when i open webview but image view doesnt disappers what to do??

Comment: The problem is not understood.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method called "setVlisivlity()" in widgets.

you can try `imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` but it's not quite recommended to do it this way.